# Get PHP Datetimezone through variables

Tags: php, datetime

This is how I get the date time of a city,

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Bangkok'));
```

instead that need to get it from variables,
I tried the below code but it not successful.

```
$type     = 'Asia';       
$type1     = 'Bangkok';

$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('$type/$type1'));
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Variables are not interpreted in single quotes. Use double-quotes: "$type/$type1"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes

```
  $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("$type/$type1"));
```

for an explanation, I will refer you to this question explaining the difference between '' and "" in PHP.

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: You should explain why... this person is obviously new to PHP.